# Defining relative paths for my Visual Studio Project files in c#

Tags: c#

So I've downloaded a framework to write code within, and I needed to link the source code to an executable file to allow the code to run. However, moved the root folder (containing all files related to the project) from the folder it was in previously, and now nothing works. I've been attempting to change the paths for the files to be relative to the root folder within the properties tab, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Path to Executible - C:\Users\me\Downloads\Competition-Pack-v43-GeometryFriends-updated-14-08-2016\GeometryFriendsAgents\GeometryFriendsGame\Release\GeometryFriends.exe

C:\Users\me\Downloads\Competition-Pack-v43-GeometryFriends-updated-14-08-2016\GeometryFriendsAgents\GeometryFriendsGame\Release

Is there an equivalent to using Macros to define paths in C#, like you get when you build a C++ project?

Comment: I've had this problem in the past.  I usually close project and edit the .proj file to fix issue.

Comment: I can fix the path to be to where its supposed to be, but I have a couple of people working with me and we don't want to be constantly changing that file everywhere we go. Is there no way to just make it relative to the root project folder, ie, the location of the .sln file?

Comment: You can use ..\..\myproject\123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out in the end that Visual Studio has a Macros option for this very task.

[image]

When you're looking at your include directories window as in the image above, there's a button labelled Macros. Click that, and it gives you access to a list of predefined paths. They all start with a $, like the ones already provided that point to the include folders for Visual Studio.

In my example above, I added `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)`, which points to the exact folder that I needed on the drive my code folder was located on. Hope I can help at least one or two people with this, cause it drove me insane until I came across it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the .exe as a resource (non embedded) to your project, and set the "Copy to output" property to copy always. This ensures the needed exe will always be relative to your build path. The simply use relative paths in your code.

Example:
(This is all done in VS's solution explorer window)
Right click your project, and add a new folder, name it Externals. 
Right click the folder, click Add, and then Existing item. Locate your exe, and add it. 
Now right click the exe, select properties, and set the "Copy to output" property to anything other than "Do not copy". 
Now, anywhere in your code, use the path "Externals\YourExe.exe". The double backslash is to unescape the backslash. An alternative would be to use @"Externals\YourExe.exe", which turns the string to a path during compile time.

There you go, when you build, the exe will be automatically copied to the build directory's "Externals" directory, and always be relative.